# php cannot run but display the whole script

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I've installed wamp64 for windows 10

Apache 2.4.27
PHP 5.6.31
MySQL 5.7.19

I have save my php script like trial.php, but the when I run,
localhost/trial.php
It came out the whole script.

Answer (score 1):

This typically means the script isn't being processed correctly. This could mean there is something wrong with WAMP or its configuration, or there is something wrong with script or file itself.

As a small FYI, you want to use long  PHP tags e.g. `<?php` and `?>`. An easy way to see if PHP is even available is to place `<?php phpinfo() ?>` in a new PHP file and try to run that rather than a more complex script. Also, if you haven't already done so, you should turn off  hiding extensionsfor known file types in Windows. It's possible your script may actually be e.g. `trial.php.txt` or similar but Windows is hiding the .txt portion.

Comment: I have try the easy way check txt.portion, but it also display the script